# How to set time equal to zero by group?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

If I have a data frame that has many rows like this:

```
  subject-id activity label    timestamp          x         y          z
1       1600              A 2.522077e+14 -0.3647613  8.793503  1.0550842
2       1600              A 2.522077e+14 -0.8797302  9.768784  1.0169983
3       1600              A 2.522078e+14  2.0014954 11.109070   2.619156
4       1600              A 2.522078e+14  0.4506226 12.651642 0.18455505
5       1600              A 2.522079e+14 -2.1643524 13.928436 -4.4224854
6       1600              A 2.522079e+14 -4.3327790 13.361191 -0.7188721
.
.
.
  subject-id activity label    timestamp           x          y          z
991      1600             B 2.519876e+14  1.37554930 15.3750460  2.9716187
992      1600             B 2.519877e+14 -3.93443300 17.5387880  2.1100159
993      1600             B 2.519877e+14 -0.08773804 12.7915650 -1.4541016
994      1600             B 2.519878e+14  2.03874200  3.0771484 -1.0537262
995      1600             B 2.519878e+14 -2.55847170 -2.7386780 -2.0985107
996      1600             B 2.519879e+14 -1.35530090  0.3884125 -0.6598511
```

How can I set the time equal to zero by group "subject-id"? I want to subtract off the first time for every instance of that group. Like this:

```
  subject-id activity label    timestamp          x         y          z
1       1600              A            0 -0.3647613  8.793503  1.0550842
2       1600              A      .050354 -0.8797302  9.768784  1.0169983
3       1600              A      .100708  2.0014954 11.109070   2.619156
4       1600              A      .151062  0.4506226 12.651642 0.18455505
.
.
.
  subject-id activity label    timestamp           x          y          z
991      1600             B            0  1.37554930 15.3750460  2.9716187
992      1600             B      .049355 -3.93443300 17.5387880  2.1100159
993      1600             B      .100601 -0.08773804 12.7915650 -1.4541016
```

Note: I made up some number for activity B to demonstrate what I mean.

What I have tried:
I tried making a function and applying the function with aggregate:

```
time_zero <- function(vec){
  result <- (vec$timestamp - vec$timestamp[1])/10E8
  return(result)
}
test <- aggregate(pa, list(pa$`activity label`), FUN = time_zero)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ave` here :

```
df$timestamp <- with(df, ave(timestamp, label, FUN = function(x) (x - x[1])/10E8))
```

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  mutate(timestamp = (timestamp - first(timestamp))/10E8)
```

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, timestamp := (timestamp - first(timestamp))/10E8, label]
```

This subtracts `timestamp` with `first` `timestamp` in each `label` dividing by 10E8.

Comment: Thank you so much! I especially love the dplyr version. It just makes the most sense to me!